# Setting subviews quicker than in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Right now I'm allocating and initializing three UIImageViews that take up the entire screen and are stacked in the viewDidLoad method.  Its actually taking some time to do this.  Is there a way to do this automatically so the view just has them before its even loaded? like an init method that would speed this up?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mySubviews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.videoCounterTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int c = (int)[self.scenes count];
c--;
NSLog(@"int c = %d", c);
self.myCounter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:c];


for (int i=0; i<=c; i++) {

    //create imageView
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // <--- This is very important
    imageView.tag = i;                        // <--- Add tag to track this subview in the view stack
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    NSLog(@"added image view %d", i);


    //get scene object
    PFObject *sceneObject = self.scenes[i];


    //get the PFFile and filetype
    PFFile *file = [sceneObject objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSString *fileType = [sceneObject objectForKey:@"fileType"];



    //check the filetype
    if ([fileType  isEqual: @"image"])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //get image
        NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:file.url];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        });

    }

    //its a video
    else
    {
        // the video player
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:file.url];

        self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];
        self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

        self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
        //self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
        [imageView.layer addSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer];

        NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];

        NSLog(@"tag = %@", tag);

        [self.videoCounterTags addObject:tag];

    }


}



UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];

// dummyScreen is just a see through view that sits on top of my image stack and holds my tap gesture recognizer
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.dummyScreen];

[self.dummyScreen addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];



}
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code so someone can offer possible solutions to what you are doing.

Comment: Can you explain why you're saying `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue...`?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe why are you loading a series of image views that overlap with each other. Usually we optimize performance (and memory characteristics) by only loading the visible images. If we understand the purpose for what you're doing, we might be able to suggest better patterns.

Comment: Well I'm trying to implement how snapchat displays their snapstories. So basically I have an array of image/video objects and I loop through that array and make imageViews for each one. If it's an image I put the image on its respective image view. If it's a video I put a AVPlayer layer on its respective image view. The reason I am stacking all these views on top of each other is so I can cycle through them by just tapping on the screen and popping that top most image view off the stack of views

Comment: I'll put the rest of the code up

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue...
```

That moves you onto a background thread, and thus there is no telling when the code will be executed. Hence the delay.

- If these are *local* files (i.e., the URL is the file URL of an image file in your app bundle), there is no need for any `dispatch_async` in your code. Remove all of that and do everything on the main thread. That way, it will happen as fast as possible.
- If these are *remote* files (i.e., you have to do networking to get hold of them), then there's probably nothing you can do to speed things up; networking takes time, and `viewDidLoad` is just about as early as you can possibly be notified that it's time to get hold of the images.

Comment: Can I download them in the background via file.url and then save them locally in a way that would make them quicker to load upon viewing them?

Comment: Yes if you know the images to download earlier. If the images are displayed often then consider caching them when they are loaded so they will potentially available from cache when next needed.

Comment: Okay so upon the launching the app I can download my PFObjects that hold the image file which i make a file url for and then I cache that image from the file url?

Comment: @user2792129 Coming up with a new strategy is up to you, but I believe I've answered the question you actually asked.